# Creating a scoring/ranking variable

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction, ranking

I have been tasked with creating a variable which is a score. There are roughly 5-10 variables which I will be factoring into this score variable. I have looked into dimensionality reduction as a starting point, specifically principal component analysis since I have had experience with this in the past. Is this a good starting point or should I be looking elsewhere? Also if it helps, I will be working exclusively in Python to achieve this task.

Additional Context: This is social media data, where I will be ranking famous pages, using variables such as fans, followers, posts, tweets, etc...

Comment: no one? This is a good question